# Redirect product pages to another site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

This is a bit of a odd situation, of needing to recode WooComm to send visitors to a separate website as their store-front (I didn't ask why, I'm just paid to "make it happen.") I've figured out thanks to StackOverflow how to do a, I guess "basic" redirect, but I need to be able to redirect something around 20 product pages to their respective mirror-products on the other site.

Below is some simple code I found here, but I need to modify slightly. The "if(is_product))" I'd like to refine to be specific to each product and to send to their mirror-products. I'm sure there's a better method, but I'm still very very new to this level of coding. And for security reasons, I'm using Google as the redirect destination for posting the code here.

```
add_action('template_redirect','custom_shop_page_redirect');
function custom_shop_page_redirect(){
if (class_exists('WooCommerce')){
    if(is_product()){
        wp_redirect( 'https://google.com' );
        exit();
    }
} 
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be able to use wp_query global to make more precise decisions.

```
global $wp_query, $post;
if (class_exists('WooCommerce')){
    if(is_product()){
        switch ( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
            case "product1" :
                wp_redirect( 'https://google.com/product1' );
                break;
            case "product2" :
                wp_redirect( 'https://google.com/product2' );
                break;
            default :
                wp_redirect( 'https://google.com/' );
                break;
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

I don't know if post_type is the exact query_var you will be looking for as maybe it is just "product" for all of them. But if you var_dump query_vars I'm sure you will find the unique identifier.

Comment: I think we're on the right line of thought. Just need to learn how to query_var to replace post_type to the correct bit.

Comment: I know its in woocomm, just don't know the codified name of it. Site.com/product/**this part**